# Creating "new" class within class (Builder pattern)

Tags: java

I'm looking at the "Builder" pattern specifically for automation coding and I came across an article: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/test-automation-improve-code-readability-using-data-nir-tal/

I'm new to C#/Java (this particular snippet is in Java). However one thing confused me was instantiating a class within a class (after `new` has already been called).

[image]

and then calling the class:

[image]

I understand what the code is doing, however in the `create()` method of `User` class, we instantiate a new `User` when a new user is already instantiated when calling `User` directly via `User validUser = new User(....)` isn't re-calling `new` sort of redundant in the `create()` method?

Maybe it's the builder pattern that is confusing, but we are already setting the values via the setters/getters, so why do we need to `create()` them?

Comment: static inner classes like these don't exist in C#, it's a Java-only concept to make up for the lack of first-class delegates and events. In other words, don't mix the two languages, they are very different.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots, post the actual code as code-formatted text.

Comment: @Blindy So how would this look different in C# for instance then?

Comment: In C# the inner class wouldn't be static and you'd have an instance variable to hold its data in the parent class. You also wouldn't create that object by calling the inner class as a function, you'd need a static method in the outer class to do it. But really, in C# you wouldn't even have the inner class at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> however in the create() method of User class, we instantiate a new User when a new user is already instantiated when calling User directly anyways via User validUser = new User(....)

`User` constructor is not called, it's not `new User()` but `new User.Builder()` (the code formatting on this example is terribly confusing), which is just a way to access the inner class `Builder` from `User` class. If `Builder` was not a static inner class, you would simply call it `new Builder()`.

With proper line-breaks it's

```
User validUser = new User.Builder()
  .setName("test@test.com")
  .setPassword("Test")
  .create();
```

Comment: That makes more sense. I didn't notice it was missing the `()` therefore not "calling" the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

User.Builder() is the class name. (Similar to calling packageName.classInPackage())  The create() method makes a user from the builder class.  The User in User.Builder() is not instantiating a new User object.